# Sending an email attachment in memory using OpenXML

Tags: email, openxml

I've got an Excel file that's built using OpenXML 2 and I want to send it as an email attachment. e.g.

```
    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    SpreadsheetDocument package = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    AddParts(package); //created using document reflector
```

Saving the spreadsheet to a temp file using

```
stream.WriteTo(new System.IO.FileStream(@"c:\test.xlsx", System.IO.FileMode.Create));
```

works fine. But trying to send the stream directly as an email attachment fails - just get an empty file attached to the email when I do

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment file = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, "MobileBill.xlsx", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Anbody know how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I got this working, though through some effort.  To create the stream:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

using (SpreadsheetDocument package = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
  Excel.CreateSpreadsheet(package, Excel_Methods.CreateSpotQuoteOut(), true);
}

stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, "spreadsheet.xlsx");

attach.ContentDisposition.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
attach.ContentDisposition.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
attach.ContentDisposition.Inline = false;
attach.ContentDisposition.Size = stream.Length;
attach.ContentType.MediaType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
```

Also, I found that mine were not being sent right after I created them, and the reason for that is "standalone=yes" was not being added to the xml declaration of all the pages, so in my AddParts function, after adding the parts, I passed them into this function:

```
private static void AddXMLStandalone(OpenXmlPart part)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(part.GetStream());

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(part.GetStream());

            doc.InnerXml = doc.InnerXml.Substring(doc.InnerXml.IndexOf("?>") + 2);
            doc.InnerXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" + doc.InnerXml;

            part.GetStream().SetLength(doc.InnerXml.Length);
            doc.Save(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();            
        }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

do this:

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment file = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()), "MobileBill.xlsx", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Apparently the memory stream doesn't get flushed or something

Answer (score 1):

For your "content unreadable" problem, make sure to Save() your Workbooks and Worksheets and enclose your SpreadsheetDocument in a using statement to ensure all packages and zipped streams are flushed, closed and so on.

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
using (SpreadsheetDocument package = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)))
{
    AddParts(package); 
    //Save if AddParts hasn't done it
}
System.Net.Mail.Attachment file =  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out load: could it be, that the Attachment class expects to read from the current possition in the provided stream? If this is the case, you would probably have to "seek" back to the beginning of the stream, before feeding it to the Attachment constructor:

```
AddParts(package); //created using document reflector
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment file = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, "MobileBill.xlsx", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Comment: thanks. getting there - it's sending data through now as I can see the size of the attachment has increased. But Excel complains that the content is unreadable.

Comment: Are you able to save the attachment and somehow diff it with the same file, as saved in your stream.WriteTo() example? Is the new file completely garbage, or does it contain some of the expected data? How much? Which parts?